# Templates do not shows up the image

Tags: python, django

The `img` tag do not shows up.
The `mem.mem_img` is `/uploads/images/team2.png`, and in my template:

```
<div>
    <img src="{{ mem.mem_img }}">
</div>
```

In the browser the image do not shows up.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

In the browser debugger:
[image]

How can I shows the image?

Comment: where is your image, go to the url and search it

Comment: Have you load static in your templates? and the absolute path of the image is what?

Comment: I have loaded the static, and the image AP is `/static/uploads/images/team2.png`

Comment: is this image in `media` folder or `static` folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app create a folder called "static". Suppose your app name is "sample" then place your image file in
"sample/static/sample/images/imagename.png" where images is the subfolder. Then try. I hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, You set the `img` src wrong.

You did not use the static path to append the image relative path.

You should use:

```
<img src= {% static mem.mem_img %}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be giving the absolute path:

```
    <div>
        <img src="{{ mem.mem_img.url }}">
    </div>
```